# react state is not rendering on coming back from edit page to details

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have a details page where am displaying the content. on click of edit am navigating to edit page, where am giving the ability to modify the data and on click of update am using 
`window.history.back();` to coming back to details page, where the data showed is not the updated one.

i have to use history there as i have some other functionalities associated with this.

Observations : state is getting updated but its not rendering for first time, when edit and update for second time, first time updated data is displayed on details page.

Comment: Are you using Axios?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide code which you are using in update/edit screen to update the data. it would be something like this.setState({ ......... }).

Reason may be that the first screen is rendered before the states have been updated.

Try using `this.setState({ <update data here> }, window.history.back());`

Comment: from update/edit screen am updating the db. after that am using 'window.histoty.back()' to go back to the details page. on details page am calling the db and getting the data again. am getting data and saving it in a state. but its not rendering at first time. if i refresh page(F5) it appears. Sorry can't share the code.

Comment: May be your setState line is executed before the data is retrieved, which generally happens in asynchronous calls.

Comment: Suppose if we use fetch() method to get data, so we can do some thing like below :-
`fetch( <url> ).then((response) => {
  this.setState({ <update state here> }) 
})`
you can use other ways also to handle asynchronousness.

Comment: i solved it by adding 'catch:false' for ajax call. Thanks for the help